# Google maps API key not being added

Tags: mx-google-map

I'm updating an EE site from 2.3.x to 2.10.3 and as part of that I'm upgrading mx_google_map from 1.4 to 1.5.3.

Using the field type on the front end I get the following console error:

Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

I have this in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/third_party/mx_google_map/mxgooglemap.js"></script>
```

On the live site the api key is included but in the updated site it doesn't appear to work.

The test site I'm using is on a sub-domain and I wonder if that's the cause of the problem or is it down to the extension.

Should I specify the API key somewhere, am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the key as a GET parameter to the API source script tag:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_GOES_HERE&sensor=true
```

I've seen this issue in some places, as well as right here! :

[Google Maps for EE stopped plotting markers for new entries in the control panel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34899/google-maps-for-ee-stopped-plotting-markers-for-new-entries-in-the-control-panel)

Comment: Excellent thanks. I even thought about doing that. Doh!